# Modify a DateType variable

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building a filter to choose elements by date min and date max.
The formbuilder return me the dates on YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS format but with HH-MM-SS always equal to 00-00-00.

But i want my date max to be YYYY-MM-DD 23-59-59.Anyway i can modify my date max?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is the formbuilder code

```
->add(
                'date_max',
                DateType::class,
                [
                    'label'         => 'Date max',
                    'attr' => ['style' => 'width: 1000px'],
                    'required'      => false,
                    'empty_data'    => null
                ]
            );
```

This is the querybuilder code

```
    if ($datemax !== null) {
        $qb->andWhere('q.date_creation >= :date_max')
            ->setParameter('date_max', $datemax);
```

My issue is,my formbuilder give me a datetype which looks like :

```
object(DateTime)#43691 (3) {  ["date"]=&gt;  string(26) "2018-07-25 00:00:00.000000"["timezone_type"]=&gt;  int(3)  ["timezone"]=&gt;  string(3) "UTC"}
```

and i want it to be  like:

```
object(DateTime)#43691 (3) {  ["date"]=&gt;  string(26) "2018-07-25 23:59:59.000000"["timezone_type"]=&gt;  int(3)  ["timezone"]=&gt;  string(3) "UTC"}
```

So that when my sql query executes i can acces to date_max's creations.

Sorry that my post is kinda messy(my english is not that good)

Comment: You should post the relevant code. Without that, the only thing I can suggest is to add a day and subtract a second.

Comment: Why not just use a date if you're not interested in the time?

Comment: Your question is unclear because you did not post relevant code, but I assume you're asking how you can create and manipulate a DateTime object, right? If that is the case you should have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php and try to apply jeroen's solution.

Comment: Work with `\DateTimeImmutable` instead. If you don't really know how objects and references work, you eventually will end up with weird and unexpected results.

Comment: Please see the edit to my question (**Edit 2**). I think this answers your edited question. If not, please provide more info to help answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DateType object ->format('Y-m-d') to specify exactly the format you want and then concatenate the 23:59:59 later.

Is this more or less what you wanted?

Also, you can include the constants on the format string, like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2018/01/01');

// Output year with constant time
echo $date->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
```

Comment: Yes,this is what i wanted.But how can you concatenate DateType Object and a string 23:59:59?

Comment: When you use the DateType object with the ->format function, the output is a string.

Then you can just concatenate `$date->format('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59'` . and you should have the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because who has time to read [manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)?

```
$date_string = "2018-07-31 00:00:00";
$date = new DateTime($date_string);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
// set the time to 1 second before midnight
$date->setTime(23, 59, 59);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
2018-07-31 00:00:00
2018-07-31 23:59:59
```

**Edit**

Just noticed you said the time format was HH-MM-SS. If that is truly the case, you will need this code instead:

```
$date_string = "2018-07-31 00-00-00";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H-i-s', $date_string);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H-i-s') . "\n";
$date->setTime(23, 59, 59);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H-i-s') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
2018-07-31 00-00-00
2018-07-31 23-59-59
```

**Edit 2**

Given that you already have a DateTime object, all you have to do is set the time:

```
var_dump($date);
// set the time to 1 second before midnight
$date->setTime(23, 59, 59);
var_dump($date);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-07-31 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-07-31 23:59:59.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Comment: Well, truth be told, if everyone read manuals before, there wouldn't be much point in coming to Stack Overflow after all, would it? :)